# Multiple emails when triggered from SendGrid remain undelivered and stay in "Processed" state

Tags: email, process, sendgrid

I am using `SendGrid` to send email notifications. I have a requirement where I send multiple reminder emails once a day.

Currently, I am facing an issue with this. When the emails are triggered, ideally 5 emails should be sent from the application but instead of that only 1 mail is received. When checked in the logs and SendGrid dashboard it is observed that the emails are triggered but they stay in a `Processed` state which stops them from being delivered to the respective recipients.

I am not understanding what is this issue about and why is this happening even after receiving success code from SendGrid.

Answer (score 1):

The success code from SendGrid just means that they received the message properly from you. Email is asynchronous, and the SendGrid `200` doesn't mean the message was delivered. In your SendGrid Email Activity, look and see if you have [Deferred events](https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/email_activity.html) for those additional messages; trying to send multiple messages to the same address at the same moment may be causing warmup-based deferrals, until the receiving system trusts you.